# What is the most efficient way to aggregate a value from a JSON tree in d3.js?

Tags: json, d3.js, tree, aggregate, hierarchical-data

Assume you have a D3 JSON input with an unordered tree hierarchy like this:

```
{
"generated": "2017-02-21T14:02:18.652071",
"name": "root",
"children": [
{
  "name": "level1",
  "module_name": "level1",
  "children": [

  ],
  "size": "16"
},
{
  "authorid": "46f14ba664314322e217383c4166d9e89892de93cbe2bb6bf2ea1645f910a24955c22fd384924a2f715efa34d07149ba284c2947c788f7c25a99308dfb2d7a6c",
  "name": "child.js",
  "weight": "1.0",
  "module_name": "child.js",
  "children": [

  ],
  "size": "14"
},
{
  "authorid": "46f14ba664314322e217383c4166d9e89892de93cbe2bb6bf2ea1645f910a24955c22fd384924a2f715efa34d07149ba284c2947c788f7c25a99308dfb2d7a6c",
  "name": "child_1.js",
  "weight": "1.0",
  "module_name": "child_1.js",
  "children": [
      {
        "authorid": "e5b333a985d12c2f0ccc878fc81d5e3d04732ef398631022443e25c2372e165f4f0d3d61f3f8caf8ccf4fa6e6af336834062d883d52fd3b67b2e15bd8599207a",
        "name": "child_1_1.js",
        "module_name": "child_1_1.js",
        "children": [

        ],
        "size": "112"
      },  
  ],
  "size": "14"
},
{
  "authorid": "e5b333a985d12c2f0ccc878fc81d5e3d04732ef398631022443e25c2372e165f4f0d3d61f3f8caf8ccf4fa6e6af336834062d883d52fd3b67b2e15bd8599207a",
  "name": "child_3.js",
  "module_name": "child_3.js",
  "children": [

  ],
  "size": "133"
}...
```

The structure can have any depth.

Now we need to aggregate / group all "authorid" values so we have a grouped array / map of the containing hashes of all authors from the nested JSON tree like this:

```
[
"46f14ba664314322e217383c4166d9e89892de93cbe2bb6bf2ea1645f910a24955c22fd384924a2f715efa34d07149ba284c2947c788f7c25a99308dfb2d7a6c",
"e5b333a985d12c2f0ccc878fc81d5e3d04732ef398631022443e25c2372e165f4f0d3d61f3f8caf8ccf4fa6e6af336834062d883d52fd3b67b2e15bd8599207a",
]
```

All duplicates should be aggregated as string values into a grouped value list.

The purpose of the resulting array is to filter a html table from the according node entrys that are visible in the d3 chart.

What is the most elegant way to reach this without plain javascript recursion. Is it possible to use a nested JSON as input for d3.nest or is there another performant way i.e. filter to get the above result?

Answer (score 2):

If you are free to use ES6 features, one of the cleanest solutions can be implemented using a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) for recursively walking through the data structure in combination with a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) allowing only unique entries.

```
function* getAuthorIds(arr) {
  for (let {authorid, children} of arr) { 
    if (authorid) yield authorid;
    if (children) yield* getAuthorIds(children);
  }
}

var uniqueAuthorIds = [...new Set(getAuthorIds(data))];
```

The generator function gets passed an array of objects over which it will iterate using a *for-of* loop. It will [`yield`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) the `authorid` if the object contains a property of this name. After that, it checks, if the object contains an array of `children` and, if it does, delegates to the generator for these children by using [`yield*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*). This is where recursion happens to walk through the entire hierarchy.

To get a collection of unique `authorid`s you can construct a `Set` from all values of `authorid`, which were found throughout your data. The `Set` by definition guarantees the values stored in it to be unique. The trick here is to pass the generator created for your data by calling `getAuthorIds(data)` directly to the `Set`'s constructor. This is possible because the constructor accepts an iterable object, i.e. an object implementing the [iterable protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterable_protocol), which is exactly what a [`Generator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) implicitly does.

Because in your question you asked for an array of `authorid`s, as a last step, an array is created from the Set using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

Have a look at the following working demo:

```js
var data = [{
"generated": "2017-02-21T14:02:18.652071",
"name": "root",
"children": [{
  "name": "level1",
  "module_name": "level1",
  "children": [

  ],
  "size": "16"
  }, {
    "authorid": "46f14ba664314322e217383c4166d9e89892de93cbe2bb6bf2ea1645f910a24955c22fd384924a2f715efa34d07149ba284c2947c788f7c25a99308dfb2d7a6c",
    "name": "child.js",
    "weight": "1.0",
    "module_name": "child.js",
    "children": [

    ],
    "size": "14"
  }, {
    "authorid": "46f14ba664314322e217383c4166d9e89892de93cbe2bb6bf2ea1645f910a24955c22fd384924a2f715efa34d07149ba284c2947c788f7c25a99308dfb2d7a6c",
    "name": "child_1.js",
    "weight": "1.0",
    "module_name": "child_1.js",
    "children": [{
          "authorid": "e5b333a985d12c2f0ccc878fc81d5e3d04732ef398631022443e25c2372e165f4f0d3d61f3f8caf8ccf4fa6e6af336834062d883d52fd3b67b2e15bd8599207a",
          "name": "child_1_1.js",
          "module_name": "child_1_1.js",
          "children": [

          ],
          "size": "112"
    }],
    "size": "14"
  }, {
    "authorid": "e5b333a985d12c2f0ccc878fc81d5e3d04732ef398631022443e25c2372e165f4f0d3d61f3f8caf8ccf4fa6e6af336834062d883d52fd3b67b2e15bd8599207a",
    "name": "child_3.js",
    "module_name": "child_3.js",
    "children": [

    ],
    "size": "133"
  }]
}];

function* getAuthorIds(arr) {
  for (let {authorid, children} of arr) { 
    if (authorid) yield authorid;
    if (children) yield* getAuthorIds(children);
  }
}

var uniqueAuthorIds = [...new Set(getAuthorIds(data))];

console.log(uniqueAuthorIds);
```

Comment: That's a great answer. It won't work on IE but... who cares?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I am always hesitating posting answers containing many ES6 feature, and those posts of mine which do, usually start off with something like *If you are free to use ES6...*. But, hey, it's an official standard, the implementations across modern browsers are not *that* bad, so, it's time to step up!

Comment: Some months ago I used this exactly same code (spread with new set) to remove duplicates. The first thing I had asked to my client was *"do you want me to give support to IE?"*. I can only hope that, some day in the near future, IE will be a memory from the past. Btw, I just used it in an answer:http://stackoverflow.com/a/42522793/5768908

Comment: Preferred solution. This would not be my accepted if i had the possibility to use ES6 features. The function is needed for a end user application and we have roundabout 20% trident bases browsers on client side. Anyway, many thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think d3 is not needed for this task as a simple recursive function should fit pretty well.

```js
var ids = [];
function collectAuthorIdsRecursively(elem) {
    for (var i = 0; i < elem.children.length; i++) {
        var child = elem.children[i];
        if (child.hasOwnProperty('authorid') && ids.indexOf(child.authorid) < 0) {
            ids.push(child.authorid);
        }

        if (child.hasOwnProperty('children') && child.children instanceof Array) {
            collectAuthorIdsRecursively(child);
        }
    }
}

collectAuthorIdsRecursively(data);
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/ba6ou1sL/)

Comment: You are right. The plain iterator works best for my needs. I wrapped the iterator in a parent function outside of d3 to return a array of keys.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

```js
var jsonObj = {
 "generated": "2017-02-21T14:02:18.652071",
 "name": "root",
 "children": [{
  "name": "level1",
  "module_name": "level1",
  "children": [

  ],
  "size": "16"
 }, {
  "authorid": "46f14ba664314322e217383c4166d9e89892de93cbe2bb6bf2ea1645f910a24955c22fd384924a2f715efa34d07149ba284c2947c788f7c25a99308dfb2d7a6c",
  "name": "child.js",
  "weight": "1.0",
  "module_name": "child.js",
  "children": [

  ],
  "size": "14"
 }, {
  "authorid": "46f14ba664314322e217383c4166d9e89892de93cbe2bb6bf2ea1645f910a24955c22fd384924a2f715efa34d07149ba284c2947c788f7c25a99308dfb2d7a6c",
  "name": "child_1.js",
  "weight": "1.0",
  "module_name": "child_1.js",
  "children": [{
   "authorid": "e5b333a985d12c2f0ccc878fc81d5e3d04732ef398631022443e25c2372e165f4f0d3d61f3f8caf8ccf4fa6e6af336834062d883d52fd3b67b2e15bd8599207a",
   "name": "child_1_1.js",
   "module_name": "child_1_1.js",
   "children": [

   ],
   "size": "112"
  }],
  "size": "14"
 }]
};

var arr = [];

function checkKey(object) {
    if(object.hasOwnProperty('authorid'))
        arr.push(object.authorid);

    for(var i=0;i<Object.keys(object).length;i++) {
        if(typeof object[Object.keys(object)[i]]=="object"){
            checkKey(object[Object.keys(object)[i]]);
        }
    }
}

checkKey(jsonObj);

console.log(arr);
```