# Sort a list with D3 showing only unique values

Tags: javascript, sorting, d3.js

I need to sort a list on D3 showing unique values. I can sort it but it's showing all the occurrences for it. The file is a csv and I want to sort it by its "Zip Code" column. Just for background, I'm going to use this list later for a drop down menu, so this is a way to filter my data.

This is what I have:

```
var heatmapChart = d3.csv("heatmap.csv", function(buckets) {
    buckets.sort(function(a, b){
        return d3.ascending(a["Zip Code"], b["Zip Code"]); 
    })
```

Which gives me a sorted list like:

```
10001
10001
10001
10005
10005
...
```

I also used:

```
d3.map(buckets, function(d) { return d["Zip Code"]; }).size();
```

Following a [post here](https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/472) by @mbostock but that didn't do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using ES6, in order to get the unique values in an array of objects (here called `data`) you can do simply this :

```
var buckets = [...new Set(data.map(d => d.zip))];
```

Let's see it in action. In the following demos, I'm using a `<pre>` element to reproduce a CSV, since the Stack snippet doesn't allow me to upload a real CSV file. Besides that, I'm using a CSV with two columns, to better simulate a real situation (`d3.csv` gives you an array of objects, not a simple array, as your question may suggest).

In this first demo we use the `sort()` function only. You can see that the data is sorted, but we have repeated values:

```js
var data = d3.csvParse(d3.select("#csv").text());

data.sort(function(a, b) {return d3.ascending(a.zip, b.zip);});

console.log(data.map(d=>d.zip));
```

```css
pre{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<pre id="csv">name,zip
a,1001
b,1003
c,1008
d,1005
e,1001
f,1003
g,1007
h,1002
i,1003
j,1008
k,1002</pre>
```

Now the same code, using the spread operator and `new Set()`. This is a two-step solution: first we sort the data, and after that we create the array with unique values. Check it:

```js
var data = d3.csvParse(d3.select("#csv").text());

data.sort(function(a, b) {return d3.ascending(a.zip, b.zip);});

var buckets = [...new Set(data.map(d => d.zip))];

console.log(buckets);
```

```css
pre{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<pre id="csv">name,zip
a,1001
b,1003
c,1008
d,1005
e,1001
f,1003
g,1007
h,1002
i,1003
j,1008
k,1002</pre>
```

**EDIT**: Here is a pre-ES6 solution, asked by OP:

```js
var data = d3.csvParse(d3.select("#csv").text());

data.sort(function(a, b) {return d3.ascending(a.zip, b.zip);});

var buckets = data.map(function(d){ return d.zip}).filter(function(value, index, self){
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
});

console.log(buckets);
```

```css
pre{
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<pre id="csv">name,zip
a,1001
b,1003
c,1008
d,1005
e,1001
f,1003
g,1007
h,1002
i,1003
j,1008
k,1002</pre>
```

Comment: Great but what if we want a pre-ES6 solution?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado A strictly pre-ES6 solution won't be able to use fat arrows, though ;-) Although, admittedly, they are much more wide-spread than most other features. Just saying.

Comment: I appreciate that, I was not paying attention. Edited. And thanks for the comma: that's what happens when you use your mobile to write/edit.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Just to be a little more nitpicky: When writing *"Besides that, I'm using a CSV with two rows..."* you actually do mean *columns*, right! Take it as a compliment! I am thoroughly sifting through your posts ;-)